# Vector that spans one-dimensional subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> One-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, namely $K$ is perpendicular through the origin with the plane $P = \{s (6, 4, 6) + t(8, 6, 4) \mid s,t \in \mathbb{R}\}.$ Find the vector that spans $K.$
>
> **Hint**: The cross-product of vectors $u, v$ is perpendicular to both $u$ and $v$.

So intuitively this makes sense to me, I would need to find the position vector(?) that's perpendicular to the plane since that would be the one that spans $K$? One of my classmates told me that I could just find the span of $(6, 4, 6)$ and $(8, 6, 4)$ and take the cross-product of that, but this doesn't seem right to me. What does even the span of $(6, 4, 6)$ and $(8, 6, 4)$ represent? The span of the plane?

Comment: The span is P, which is the plane. As your classmate said, just take the cross product of the two vectors.

Comment: See how to find a [normal to a plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3288202/721644). I recently posted a, to a certain degree, [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3704461/721644) with picture that might help you visualize your task.